# After XCode 14.3, ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/TurboModuleUtils.h: No such file or directory

Tags: xcode, react-native

I can't build my company's 0.65 project after upgrading xcode to 14.3 today.

however I can build my personal 0.69 project.

I can't solve even after removing cache folders and npm modules.. Pods...

React Native Version 0.65.3

```
System:
OS: macOS 13.0.1
CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
Memory: 150.35 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
Node: 18.15.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.19 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 9.5.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 2023.02.06.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.12.0 - /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: DriverKit 22.4, iOS 16.4, macOS 13.3, tvOS 16.4, watchOS 9.4
Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335
Xcode: 14.3/14E222b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 11.0.11 - /usr/bin/javac
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: 6.0.0 => 6.0.0
react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
react-native: 0.65.3 => 0.65.3
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
react-native: Not Found
```

Steps to reproduce
Upgrade Xcode to 14.3
rebuild project based 0.65
Snack, code example, screenshot, or link to a repository

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ9mz.jpg)

I can't understand why xcode is trying to find ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/TurboModuleUtils.h not ReactCommon/react/nativemodule/core/ReactCommon/TurboModuleUtils.h
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbYdi.png)

should I downgrade xcode to 14.2??

I tried to ask to react-native issues.
But I got this email.

Unsupported Version of React Native
ℹ️  It looks like your issue or the example you provided uses an unsupported version of React Native. Due to the number of issues we receive, we're currently only accepting new issues against one of the supported versions. Please upgrade to latest and verify if the issue persists (alternatively, create a new project and repro the issue in it). If you cannot upgrade, please open your issue on StackOverflow to get further community support.

I wish to build my rn 0.65 project with xcode 14.3

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: @PhilHudson https://toyboy2.medium.com/xcode-14-3-turbomoduleutils-h-no-such-file-or-directory-a54e78a4eae5
you can see a solution at the end of the article...